# Show Tooltip in textfield on focus, Ext JS 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have to show a tooltip with xtemplate on focus event of a textfield

I have tried the following code,

```
           var tf = new Ext.form.TextField({
               name: 'name',
               fieldLabel: 'field label',
               width: 100,
               allowBlank: false,
               listeners        : {
                    focus : function(tb, e) {
                         Ext.QuickTips.register({
                           target: tf,
                           title: 'QT Title',
                           text: 'QT Text'
                         });
                     }
               }                                                                                                                           
           });
```

Any help is must appreciated.

Comment: Please note that there is a syntax error. You must place a `,` after `allowBlank: false`. And try a `console.log('test');` in the `focus`-handler before calling `Ext.QuickTips.register` to make sure the event is handled correctly.

Comment: Did you initialize the QuickTips singleton? Try adding `Ext.QuickTips.init()` before the textfield initialization. Also, I don't know what your use case is, but your code will register a qtip everytime you focus on your textfield. You might want to consider initializing in the `afterrender` listener instead.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the QuickTips init MK suggested looks like a simple typo with the function param listing "tb" rather than the "tf" you're feeding to the "target" property.